# Функция не определена

Tags: javascript

Я пишу свой сайт, и тут вроде бы всё было нормально, но через какое то время появилось это в консоли браузера:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Regs is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Что делать ?

Код :

```
<input type="submit" value="Регистрация" onclick="Regs()" id="submeet">
```

Comment: `Что делать ?` - исправлять

Comment: Нужно либо определить эту функцию, либо убрать ее вызов.

Comment: вопрос криво сформулирован, непонятно где именно в коде у вас ошибка, и какой собственно код

Comment: конкурс ясновидящих...

Comment: Код : <input type="submit" value="Регистрация" onclick="Regs()" id="submeet">